# Java. Округление чисел

Tags: java, числа

Существует ли стандартный метод округления числа до первой цифры после нуля, то есть
0.128 -> 0.1; 0.0256 -> 0.03; 0.00512 -> 0.005 ?

Comment: Нету, по одной простой причине. В типе `double` **не существует** числа, равного в точности 0.1 (поскольку 0.1 не является двоичной дробью). Миссия невыполнима!

Comment: Но с `BigDecimal` такое провернуть можно.

Answer (score 5):

Как объяснил в комментариях VladD, для `float` или `double` формально такого сделать не получится из-за машинного представления чисел (т.е. можно округлить `0.125` до `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`, что *почти* равно `0.1`, но всё же не совсем).

Но если у вас числа в `BigDecimal`, то это можно сделать как-то так:

```
public static BigDecimal roundToOneSignificantDigit(BigDecimal d) {
    return d.setScale(d.signum() == 0 ? 0 : d.scale() - d.precision() + 1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}
```

Например,

```
System.out.println(roundToOneSignificantDigit(new BigDecimal("0.00125")).toPlainString());
System.out.println(roundToOneSignificantDigit(new BigDecimal("2.5")).toPlainString());
System.out.println(roundToOneSignificantDigit(new BigDecimal("250")).toPlainString());
System.out.println(roundToOneSignificantDigit(new BigDecimal("0.0")).toPlainString());
```

напечатает

```
0.001
3
300
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Для практических целей можно сделать несложный "округлятель", используя метод Math.round():

```
public class myTest {

  static double[] testData = {
    3, 30, 300, 3000, 3465, 3567, 0.0128, 
    0.00006, 0.00007, 0.00008, 0.00009,  
    0.00256, -0.000512, -0.0000552, -3465, -3567, 
    -3444444444444449f,
  };

  static double round(double x) {
    double sign = 1;
    if (x < 0) { sign = -1; x = -x; }
    int exp = (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(x)); // Показатель степени у 10
    double pow = Math.pow(10, exp);           // 10^exp  
    return sign * Math.round(x / pow) * pow ; 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= testData.length - 1; i++)
      System.out.printf("x = %g, round(x) = %g\n", 
          testData[i], round(testData[i]));
  }

}
```

При этом нужно учитывать, что результат такого "округления" не является круглым числом в строгом смысле: он может отличаться от ожидаемого в 16-м знаке (иногда даже в 15-м), и может возвращать некруглое значение даже для круглого исходного значения. Если вы замените формат `%g` на `%s`, то увидите горькую правду:
`x = 6,00000e-05, round(x) = 6.000000000000001E-5`
 -- и тому подобное. 
Причина этого названа в комментариях к вопросу: числа, являющиеся круглыми в десятичной системе, не являются круглыми в двоичной, и многие "круглые в n-ном разряде" десятичные дроби в принципе не могут быть точно представлены в виде `double`.